# Print triangle in java using single for loop

Tags: java, algorithm

```
1
2 3
4 5 6
```

I have to print the triangle using single for loop.

I have tried using two for loops and i did it successfully but i have to solve it using single for loop.

Comment: WHy you need to do this in single loop? Even if you are doing the same thing with one loop or multiple loops the complexity remains the same!!

Answer (score 1):

The trick is that the **last number** of the **current row** is the sum of the **previous row last number** and the **number of the row**

In other words: `lastNum = prevLastNumber + rowNum`

```
int row = 1;
int last = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < 37; i++) {
    if (i < (row + last)) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    } else {
        System.out.print(i + "\n");
        row++;
        last = i;
    }
}
```

And the output is the following:

```
1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21
22 23 24 25 26 27 28
29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public class Pyramid7Floyds {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


           int nextNumber = 1;
           for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                  for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                        System.out.print(nextNumber<10 ? ("  " + nextNumber++) : (" " + nextNumber++) );  //2spaces in single digit & 1 space in double digit.
                        //System.out.format("%3d",nextNumber++ ); //You may use this line for formatting as a replacement of above line. (comment above line before using this)
                  }
                  System.out.println();
           }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        int j=1;
        for(int i=1;i<=6;i++){
            System.out.print(i+" ");
            if (i==j){
                System.out.print('\n');
                j=2*j+1;
            }
        }
     }
}
```